# Invalid type while writing to BigQuery from Apache Beam Go SDK

Tags: go, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

While I try to write to BigQuery using Apache Beam Go SDK, I got :

```
panic: element type is struct { TaskId string; Connector string; ... }, 
want struct { TaskId string "json:\"task_id\" bigquery:\"task_id\""; Connector string "json:\"connector\" bigquery:\"connector\""; ... }`
```

Here's my code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "encoding/json"
    "flag"
    "github.com/apache/beam/sdks/go/pkg/beam/io/bigqueryio"
    "github.com/apache/beam/sdks/go/pkg/beam/x/debug"
    "time"

    "github.com/apache/beam/sdks/go/pkg/beam"
    "github.com/apache/beam/sdks/go/pkg/beam/io/pubsubio"
    "github.com/apache/beam/sdks/go/pkg/beam/log"
    "github.com/apache/beam/sdks/go/pkg/beam/x/beamx"
)

type (
    ProcessedTask struct {
        TaskId     string    `json:"task_id" bigquery:"task_id"`
        Connector  string    `json:"connector" bigquery:"connector"`
        // ... other fields
    }
)

func buildPipeline(s beam.Scope) {
    rawProcessedTasks := pubsubio.Read(s, "project", "topic", &pubsubio.ReadOptions{Subscription: "subscription"})

    processedTasks := beam.ParDo(s, func(ctx context.Context, data []byte) (ProcessedTask, error) {
        var task ProcessedTask
        if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &task); err != nil {
            log.Error(ctx, err)
            return task, err
        }
        return task, nil
    }, rawProcessedTasks)

    debug.Printf(s, "Task : %#v", processedTasks)

    bigqueryio.Write(s, "project", "table", processedTasks)
}

func main() {
    flag.Parse()
    beam.Init()

    p, s := beam.NewPipelineWithRoot()
    buildPipeline(s)

    ctx := context.Background()
    if err := beamx.Run(ctx, p); err != nil {
        log.Exitf(ctx, "Failed to execute pipeline: %v", err)
    }
}
```

While looking at the logs of Dataflow I see from my `debug.Printf`:

```
Task : struct { TaskId string "json:\"task_id\" bigquery:\"task_id\""; Connector string "json:\"connector\" bigquery:\"connector\""; ... }
{TaskId:"342ebd19-4bd8-4271-9970-fd4615ddd725", Connector:"optin-to-mailjet", ...}}
```

Why did I lose the correct typing in the `bigqueryio.Write` call ?

I tried to register the type to beam without success. Did I have to explicit the type somewhere ?

I took example of that official example : https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/go/examples/cookbook/tornadoes/tornadoes.go

Answer (score -1):

You're missing type registration at "init"

```
func init() {
    beam.RegisterType(reflect.TypeOf((*ProcessedTask)(nil)).Elem())
}
```